# Discarding Google O Auth access token after 1 time use

Tags: google-oauth

I am using Google O auth. I extract User info using the access_token by using the api - https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN I want this to be of one time use so that when this api is hit again with the same ACCESS_TOKEN, it should throw an error.

Comment: That's not really a use-case for access tokens.  They are intended to provide access for a period of time.  Access tokens are not really revokable - they're signed and typically have a short life so the act of using them does not require a trip back to the AS to verify it or prevent it from being used.  In your case, you have better luck issuing the token with a very short lifetime.  This is different that single-use, but fits the purpose of an access token better.

Comment: There is one issue which I faced recently- The access_token gives user info even when i replace the last character of the token with some other token. In those cases I'm getting the same response for both "the given token" and the "tampered token". How can I prevent that?

Comment: The token (jwt in your case) has three parts: the header, the payload and the signature.  If the signature is not valid (anything changed in the token since its been signed) then the token should be ignored (because it's been tampered with).  There's no mechanism for changing a token - you would create a new one and re-sign it.  Or in your case, Google would issue a new token with new claims in it.